# Automatically map all XML tags to class using Automapper

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

How to map each of `TAG` tags of this `XmlDocument` **without explicitly indicating all member mappings**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULT>
  <TAG ID="foo">Hello</TAG>
  <TAG ID="bar">World</TAG>
  ... (huge amount of tags)
<RESULT>
```

to class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    ... (huge amount of properties)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<XmlDocument,Result>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ResolveUsing(res =>
    {
        XmlDocument document = (XmlDocument)res.Context.SourceValue;

        var node = document
            .DocumentElement
            .ChildNodes
            .OfType<XmlElement>()
            .FirstOrDefault(
                element =>
                    element
                    .GetAttribute("ID")
                    .Equals(res.Context.MemberName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (node == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not find a corresponding node in the XML document");

        return node.InnerText;

    }));
```

Please note that you can decide to use a different approach to find the appropriate node inside the `XmlDocument`. For example, you might decide to use XPath.

Also note that I am throwing an exception if a corresponding node is not found in the `XmlDocument`. You might decide to do something else in this case. For example, you might decide to return null, an empty string, or some default value.